# Set Default Classes For Submit Button In Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, button, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I'm using [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) with Rails 3.2. I'm currently adding the same classes to the submit button of each form within my app. There are a lot of forms so this isn't very DRY.

```
<%= f.button :submit, class: "form-submit" %>
```

Is there a way to configure Simple Form to use a default class for all submit buttons?

Answer (score 8):

Actually it is possible to add default class to button in simple form.
In **config/initializers/simple_form.rb**:

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # Default class for buttons
  config.button_class = 'btn form-submit'
end
```

Tested in Simple Form 3.0.1
Remember to restart server after making changes to files in initializers directory.

Comment: This only seems to work for `f.button :submit`, not `f.submit`.  Is there a way to make it work for both?

Comment: Just make sure that if you installed simple form with bootstrap, you change `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` instead of `simple_form.rb`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible to add a default class for the submit button in a configuration file.

However, if this is really bothering you, you can change the generator for a form and add a default class for the submit button.

Copy the default [form template](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/_form.html.erb) to `lib/generators/simple_form/templates/_form.html.erb` and make the changes. Now, if the form create task is called, this template will be used.

Comment: As Gee-Bees answer states this is totally possible.